# Convert Ninject WhenInjectedInto bindings to Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Im trying to convert some Ninject bindings to Autofac, but can not get it to work.

Theese are the ninject bindings:

```
        Bind<SearchEngineSettings>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<SearchEngineProvider<KreditorSearchEngineItem>>()
            .WithPropertyValue("Path", Path.Combine(_settings.LuceneRoot, @"Kreditor"));

        Bind<SearchEngineSettings>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<SearchEngineProvider<MedlemSearchEngineItem>>()
            .WithPropertyValue("Path", Path.Combine(_settings.LuceneRoot, @"Medlem"));

        Bind<SearchEngineSettings>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<SearchEngineProvider<LejerSearchEngineItem>>()
            .WithPropertyValue("Path", Path.Combine(_settings.LuceneRoot, @"Lejer"));

        Bind<SearchEngineSettings>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<SearchEngineProvider<InteressentSearchEngineItem>>()
            .WithPropertyValue("Path", Path.Combine(_settings.LuceneRoot, @"Interessent"));

        Bind<SearchEngineSettings>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<SearchEngineProvider<LejemaalSearchEngineItem>>()
           .WithPropertyValue("Path", Path.Combine(_settings.LuceneRoot, @"Lejemaal"));
```

This is what i have tryed, that does not work (1 out of them, same principle):

```
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var settings = c.Resolve<Shared.SharedSettings.Settings>();
            return new SearchEngineSettings() { Path = Path.Combine(settings.LuceneRoot, @"Kreditor") };
        }).Named<SearchEngineSettings>("searchKreditor");
        builder.RegisterType<SearchEngineProvider<KreditorSearchEngineItem>>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<SearchEngineSettings>("searchKreditor"));
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it should work, I did a small code sample to illustrate it : https://dotnetfiddle.net/MNdFSj Do you have any error message ?